# How do I get Dash Doc App to respect indentation on MacVim?

Tags: vim, text-editors, macvim, textexpander

Couldn't do the same as the answer in the question below.

[How do I get Dash Doc App to respect indentation?](https://superuser.com/questions/596073/how-do-i-get-dash-doc-app-to-respect-indentation)

Has someone run into the same problem with Vim?

--

Edit: I can't reuse the question above because I can't comment yet. Still, I think the problem, as well the solution, is different because of the tool.

Comment: If you do not find answer for a particular question, try to place comments on the answer that has been posted to attact attention rather than posting the same question again.

Comment: Hey @Prasanna, unfortunately I need 50 reputation for that and mine is 1. Hope to start get some with this question as I see that in a specific way, the questions are different. Thanks!

Comment: I have been in the same place before. Start answering some questions if you can. Post real questions - in a few hours you will have the required reps to do what you need. Now you have 6 :-)

Comment: Advice on how to use Stack Exchange / Super User: Don’t say things like “Couldn’t do the same as the answer in the question below.”  First of all, it’s not very good English.  Secondly, it’s saying “I have the same problem as the one described in [this other page](http://superuser.com/q/596073/150988); if you want to find out about my problem, go look over there.”  People are willing to help, but if you throw roadblocks and detours at us, we’re less likely to go the extra mile simply *to find out what your question is*.  Instead, describe your problem clearly and thoroughly enough … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  that people can understand it without needing to look elsewhere.  The title should describe and summarize the question, but the question body should be independently intelligible; do not use the title as the first sentence of the question.  Describe what you have done to solve the problem yourself.  In that context, mention that you found that other question that is somewhat similar to your problem, but, since your question is about MacVim and the other is about Sublime Text, it’s no big surprise that the answer there is of little use to you.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  OK, I don’t use Mac, and I’m totally unfamiliar with Dash Doc App.  The link *on the other question* has gone stale; it just goes to a generic page for the Mac App Store.  This comes back to what I was saying about making your question self-contained.  I literally *cannot* understand what you are asking, because you haven’t explained it properly.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  That said, I did look at Cory’s question from 2013, and the answer gave me a hint as to what the question was about.  And I do know `vi`/`vim` somewhat well, so I have a suggestion: try using vi’s autoindent mode.  Type `:set ai` (or `:se ai`), then do whatever it is that you do with Dash Doc App and report back to us.   (By the way, I believe that “How do I get MacVim to respect indentation with Dash Doc App?” might be a better title.)